# App Transport Security: NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed

Tags: ios, swift, ios9

I have this code:

```
func loginWithBasicAuth() -> Void {

    let usernameText = username.text
    let passwordText = password.text

    let credentialData = "\(usernameText):\(passwordText)".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let base64Credentials = credentialData?.base64EncodedStringWithOptions([])
    let headers = ["Authorization": "HTTP Basic \(base64Credentials)"]

    Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://api.domainname.com/v0.1/", headers: headers).responseString { aResponse in

        if let receivedString = aResponse.result.value {

            print(receivedString)

        } else {

            print("Login failed.")

        }
    }
}
```

In the console it prints:

> NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed
>   (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)
>   Login failed.

Here's the configuration in the `info.plist` file：
[image]

What's wrong？

Comment: try  `NSTemporaryExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy = NO` in your exception domain

Comment: No, nothing changes.

Comment: Add this key `NSIncludesSubdomains ` to api.domainname.com dictionary.And set it to YES to include subdomains

Comment: @Leo No, doesn't work. Is it something wrong with the `Exception Domains` format?

Comment: I notice that your request is `https`,it seems that it is not the problem of App Transport Security. Does your api server have valid Certificate?

Comment: @Leo I don't know, how do I know that?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure `NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads` is the right key to use when the connection is via `HTTPS`. You should probably use `NSThirdPartyExceptionMinimumTLSVersion` or `NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy`.

I would highly recommend reading the [App Transport Security Technote](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/technotes/App-Transport-Security-Technote/) document, specially the Diagnosing Connection Issues section.

There is a tool that may help you diagnose your domain:

```
/usr/bin/nscurl --ats-diagnostics [--verbose] URL
```

Answer (score 1):

Make NSAllowsArbitraryLoads to YES to disable ATS.

Answer (score 0):

Add `NSIncludesSubdomains` as you refer to subdomains and wants to have it also as an exception. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32331282/3151066) for more details